# Geometric Distribution vs Exponential Distribution Curve & relationship

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

The curve of Geometric Distribution is shaped according to parameter $\alpha$ using equation as
$P_{r}=\frac{ (1-\alpha) \alpha^{CW}} { 1- \alpha^{CW} }. \alpha^{-r}$. Where CW is a parameter (contention window size like 16). So probability for occurrence of r=0 to 15 is is represented as shown in figure for different values of $\alpha$. Here 'number starting from 0 are put at higher side so r='0' has highest probability and r='15' has lowest probability.

[image]

Question1. So my question is that exponential distribution also gives curve that matches shape of one of the curves of geometric distribution so how can we find value of $\alpha$ that give same curve as given by exponential distribution.
I have also read in Wikipedia that "The exponential distribution is the continuous analogue of the geometric distribution."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Question 2. So how can I prove any relationship between them like when exponential distribution equals geometric distribution?.  It is some times also referred as "truncated geometric probability  distribution"

Answer (score 1):

The geometric and exponential distributions are not the same, since they aren't even defined on the same domain. The geometric distribution lives on a discrete domain, the exponential distribution on a continuous domain. Consequently, you can't make the graphs of their density functions match perfectly. You can at most get them to look similar.

However, there is a reason why they look so similar: both are memoryless distributions, so they're both characterized by their median (at least approximately in the case of the geometric distribution, since its median is not unique in general). The best match between a geometric and exponential function should be when their medians match. The median of the exponential distribution with density function $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R,~f(x)=\frac1\lambda\exp(-\lambda x)$ is $\frac{\ln2}{\lambda}$. Now calculate the median of your geometric distribution and choose $\alpha$ such that the medians match.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Since Geometric Distribution formula does not have $\lambda$, instead $\alpha$, so how can I match them theoretically. Any hints on this would help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can still calculate the median, which will then depend on $\alpha$. Set that equal to $\frac{\ln2}{\lambda}$ and solve for $\alpha$.

Comment: I have used this formula for gettig probability of occurrence of variable 'r' with exponential distribution . It has same parameter 'CW' as in geometric distribution but $\lambda$ is not used here.                                                                                  $v2=(double) pow(2,CW)-1$ ,
$u=0.0+ getvalue(Uniform(0.0,1.0))$ and 
$r=ceil( log2(1+u*v2)$    Now how can I match exponential equation without $\lambda$ with geometric distribution with $\alpha$

Comment: Still the same: calculate their medians and set them to be equal. Then solve for $\alpha$.

Comment: The median of Geometric Distribution : $ \frac{-1}{log_{2}(1-p)} $ (from Wikipedia), should I put $p$ as probability of geometric distribution, but then it has $CW$ parameter. What value then it should have? .  Also when equating then $ \frac{-1}{log_{2}(1-p)} =\frac{\ln2}{\lambda}$ , $\lambda$ is not known. Please help, I cannot understand

Comment: The one on Wikipedia is with $CW=\infty$ and calls its parameter $p$ instead of $\alpha$. You have to calculate your medians manually according to the definition of a median: a number such that it's equally likely to get a number below or above this number. And yes, $\alpha$ will depend on $\lambda$. There are more than one exponential distribution, and the best $\alpha$ depends on which one you choose. You choose by picking some $\lambda>0$.

Comment: Thanks once again for giving time. Since i have CW=16 so should i put $\lambda=1/16$ and as $p=\alpha$ . Therefore, Should equation be  like this $\frac{-1}{log_{2}(1-\alpha)} =\ln2 * 16 $

Comment: $CW$ has nothing to do with $\lambda$. Your geometric and exponential distributions are different from those on Wikipedia. You have to calculate the median yourself, since the formula on Wikipedia doesn't hold for your version of the distributions.

Comment: This is my formula for exponential distribution $P(X=x)=\frac{r^x-r^{x-1}}{r^N-1},\,r>1$ and $P(X\le x)=\frac{r^x-1}{r^N-1} $.  It has no $\lambda$ so its median cant be  $\frac{\ln2}{\lambda}$.

Comment: My exponential distribution has this formula $P(X=x)=\frac{r^x-r^{x-1}}{r^N-1},\,r>1$ and $P(X\le x)=\frac{r^x-1}{r^N-1} $ and trunacted geometric probability distribution has this formula $P_{r}=\frac{ (1-\alpha) \alpha^{N}} { 1- \alpha^{N} }. \alpha^{-r}$. Where 'N' is number of element to choose from and 'r'=probbaility of picking a number r from N numbers. Now to solve for $\alpha$ i need median of both distributions equated. What would be the final equation to solve for $\alpha$ and get its value in range 0 to 1?