# Median from Probability distribution formula

Tags: probability-distributions, median

Can any one tell, how i can get formula for median of geometric distribution with this probability mass function formula
$P_{r}=\frac{ (1-\alpha) \alpha^{CW}} { 1- \alpha^{CW} }. \alpha^{-r}$

Comment: What are $C$ and $W$?  The PMF of $X \sim$ Geometric($p$) is of the form : 
$P(X=k)=(1-p)^kp$ when the support is $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots \}$ and  $P(X=k)=(1-p)^{k-1}p$ when the support is $\{1,2,3,\ldots \}$. So here it appears $(1-p) = \alpha$ and $p = (1-\alpha)$.

Comment: CW is a paramter, i.e. number of object to choose from. It is truncated geometric probability distribution.

Comment: I need median for my question that I asked here  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3983425/geometric-distribution-vs-exponential-distribution-curve-relationship/3983472?noredirect=1#comment8221177_3983472

Answer (score 1):

Utilize the following:

Find $m$ such that

(1) $\displaystyle P(X \le m) \ge \frac{1}{2}$

(2) $\displaystyle P(X \ge m) \ge \frac{1}{2}$

The median will be any such $m$. This can be calculated using the PMF.

**Edit**

According to [Truncated Distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution)

The median of a truncated distribution will be

$\displaystyle F^{-1}\bigg( \frac{F(a) + F(b)}{2} \bigg )$

Comment: Thanks for providing feedback. please tell me how can I get the median in terms of $\alpha$ . According to answer given to me, I need value of $\alpha$ that makes curve similar to exponential distribution. Also what $\lambda$ value should I put when equating medians of both truncated geometric and exponential distributions. Can you help me on my question here.   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3983425/geometric-distribution-vs-exponential-distribution-curve-relationship/3983472?noredirect=1#comment8221177_3983472

Comment: $F$ is cumulative function, what a & b are ?

Comment: Ok got it that 'a' and 'b' are constant (range), Do I need to put some value for 'a' and 'b' ?. Also $\alpha$ is not here so how can I get value of $\alpha$ that gives same curve as exponential distribution as suggested in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3983425/geometric-distribution-vs-exponential-distribution-curve-relationship/3983472?noredirect=1#comment8221177_3983472

Comment: My exponential distribution has this formula $P(X=x)=\frac{r^x-r^{x-1}}{r^N-1},\,r>1$ and $P(X\le x)=\frac{r^x-1}{r^N-1} $ and trunacted geometric probability distribution has this formula $P_{r}=\frac{ (1-\alpha) \alpha^{N}} { 1- \alpha^{N} }. \alpha^{-r}$. Where 'N' is number of element to choose from and 'r'=probbaility of picking a number r from N numbers. Now to solve for $\alpha$ i need median of both distributions equated. What would be the final equation to solve for $\alpha$ and get its value in range 0 to 1?

Comment: You can use my answer to calculate these medians. For exponential use the first part of my answer and for truncated geometric use the part I added that applies to truncated distributions.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you mean to use $\displaystyle P(X \le m) \ge \frac{1}{2}$ for exponential and $\displaystyle F^{-1}\bigg( \frac{F(a) + F(b)}{2} \bigg )$ for trunacted geometric?  Now should I put min and max values of 'N' in 'a' and 'b' ?.  Then how to get cumulative of constants 'a' & 'b' and then calculate $\alpha$